# Is there a way to know how many posts I have edited?

Tags: discussion, support, editing, badges

I was wondering if there is a way to know how many posts I have edited till date. This question arose because I saw that there is a badge for editing $80$ posts and I do not have that badge and I think I have edited that many posts.

---

**EDIT:** Lest it be misunderstood that I edit only for badges, let me point out that I was not aware of the existence of this badge till today. After I saw the badge, I thought I have probably edited that many posts to have earned that badge and hence was curious.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/222340) (search for "strunk" to quickly find the badge), it is stated that edits on deleted posts; your own posts; consisting only of tag changes, do not count. Every post counts at most once towards this badge. // Also, if you hover over your number of reviews in a review queue, you see your progress to the "Copy Editor" badge, i.e. the number of edits that the system has registered.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: We have [a related question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6955/progress-towards-badges) on this iste. There is a post on meta.SO about possibilities to find out, what is your progress towards various badges: [Badge progress reports](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports/).

Answer (score 10):

Go to any review queue and then move your mouse pointer over the badge progress bar. After a moment, you will get a box with several progress bars. At the "copy editor" bar, you see your number of edits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I came to know it from Lord_Farin's comment.

Comment: Much better than my answer.  (Always forget about the review queues.)

Answer (score 3):

> ***Note:*** I highly discourage people from making edits just to gain badges.

There there are at least two data.stackexchange queries that (might) help you keep track of this:

- [How many Copy Editor/Strunk & White-qualifying edits have I made?](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/104123)
- [How many Copy Editor/Strunk & White-qualifying edits have I made?](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/101481)

Comment: I did not say that I made edits just to get badge. As I said, I only became aware that there is a badge for that today. And then I felt, I have probably edited that many posts. It is unfortunate that it has been felt that I have been editing to earn a badge.

Comment: @Vishal: I don't assume that you are just going for badges.  But there _are_ users out there who do act in a manner to maximize badges as opposed to improve the site.